# installaton error in php5

Tags: software-installation

i am using ubuntu 12.04lts
i try to inslall php5 it create an error
 "1.Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
   2.Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?"

Answer (score 2):

Use `sudo` to install packages:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```